# Liquibase: SQL does not generate

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I am working on learning Liquibase. I am working on trying to generate the SQL from the changelog that I have. For some reason, the only SQL it is generating is the locking for the `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` table.

**ChangeLog**

This is located in com/example/db/changelog

```
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="drop-tables" author="ascalonian">
        <dropTable tableName="liquibase" />
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="create-tables" author="ascalonian">
        <createTable tableName="liquibase">
            <column name="id" type="NUMERIC(19,0)" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="firstname" type="VARCHAR(50)" />
            <column name="lastname" type="VARCHAR(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="update-tables" author="ascalonian">
        <addColumn tableName="liquibase">
            <column name="username" type="VARCHAR(10)" />
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**Command Line**

```
java -jar liquibase.jar 
--driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver 
--classpath=/Users/<username>/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/jtds/jtds/1.3.1/jtds-1.3.1.jar 
--changeLogFile=com/example/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml 
--url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/TestDB 
--username=username 
--password=password 
updateSQL
```

**SQL Output**

```
-- *********************************************************************
-- Update Database Script
-- *********************************************************************
-- Change Log: com/example/db/changelog/db.changelog-create.xml
-- Ran at: 8/11/15 4:28 PM
-- Against: username@jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/TestDB
-- Liquibase version: 3.4.1
-- *********************************************************************

-- Lock Database
UPDATE [dbo].[DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK] SET [LOCKED] = 1, [LOCKEDBY] = 'fe80:0:0:0:541c:15ff:fe8f:7826%9 (fe80:0:0:0:541c:15ff:fe8f:7826%9)', [LOCKGRANTED] = '2015-08-11T16:28:18.090' WHERE [ID] = 1 AND [LOCKED] = 0
GO

-- Release Database Lock
UPDATE [dbo].[DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK] SET [LOCKED] = 0, [LOCKEDBY] = NULL, [LOCKGRANTED] = NULL WHERE [ID] = 1
GO
```

I was expecting the SQL for the drop, create and update table but don't see anything.

Liquibase: Version 3.4.1
Database: MS SQL Server

Comment: To generate the SQL you would need to run this against an empty database (none of the tables in the changelog in the database). Also, your changelog is a bit strange because it starts with a drop table. That would only have an effect if the database you ran it against had already had the table created through a non-liquibase mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reproduce your issue. Have you already run the "update" command against your database? That would explain the lack of SQL (because the changes were already applied to the target DB).

The `DATABASECHANGELOG` table records which changesets have been applied. Checkout the rollbackSQL command, that will show you the undo actions